# i try use stored procedure in apirest but don't work

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, rest, stored-procedures, return-value

I need your help

I have a program in C #
That has entity frameworks 6.0.0.0
In which I am using an apiRest to access data from the ORACLE database

That said, in the database I have the procedure declared like this:

```
Create or replace PROCEDURE SP_INSERT_MATRIX
(
 V_matrixtype IN NUMBER DEFAULT 0,
 V_name IN NVARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
 V_description IN NVARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
 V_userid IN NVARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'user1',
 Retval out number
)
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO matrixcams (internalid, matrixtype, NAME, DESCRIPTION, USERID)
VALUES (MATRIXCAMS_INTERNALID_GEN.nextval, v_matrixtype, v_name, v_description, (SELECT internalId from users where username like v_userid));
Retval: = MATRIXCAMS_INTERNALID_GEN.currval;
END SP_INSERT_MATRIX;
```

In the program I have a button that I call

```
<button ng-click="RealGetListMatrix()" style="padding-right: 1px;">Refrescar</button>
```

The controller has declared the function as follows:

```
$Scope.RealGetListMatrix = function () {
 Var id = 0;
 Var Username = Object.keys (sessionStorage) .toString ()
 Id = RealSetNameListMatrix (Username);
 RefreshMatrix ();
 Alert (id);
}

Var RealSetNameListMatrix = function (myUserId) {
Var nameList = document.getElementById ("NameListMatrix");
Var descList = document.getElementById ("DescListMatrix");
Var msgCams = "";
Var InternalId = 178;

MatrixRest.postMatrix (function (matrixes) {});
Return InternalId;
}
```

In the api rest:

```
PostMatrix: function (data, callback) {
 This.post (function (responseMatrixes) {
  If (responseMatrixes.success) {
   Callback (responseMatrixes.data.matrixes);
  } Else {
  $RootScope.$broadcast('alert', {type: 'error', msg: responseData.error.message});
  }
 },data);
},
```

The controller calls the manager

```
Public IResponseMatrixes Post ()
{
 Return this.manager.PostResponseMatrixes ();
}
```

In the manager

```
Public IResponseMatrixes PostResponseMatrixes ()
{
 Repository.PostMatrix ();
 Return responseToRequest;
}
```

In the Repository

```
{
 Int myUserId = 0;
 ObjectParameter passMatrixInternalId = new ObjectParameter ("internalId", typeof (Int32));
 Using (CCTVConn context = new CCTVConn ())
 {
  Context.SP_INSERT_MATRIX (0, "test", "test", "user1", passMatrixInternalId);
 }
 Return Convert.ToInt32 (passMatrixInternalId.Value.ToString ());
}
```

Finally in the model

```
Public virtual int SP_INSERT_MATRIX (Nullable <decimal> v_MATRIXTYPE, string v_NAME, string v_DESCRIPTION, string v_USERID, ObjectParameter rETVAL)
{
 Int step = 0;
 Var v_MATRIXTYPEParameter = v_MATRIXTYPE.HasValue?
  New ObjectParameter ("V_MATRIXTYPE", v_MATRIXTYPE):
  New ObjectParameter ("V_MATRIXTYPE", typeof (decimal));    
 Var v_NAMEParameter = v_NAME! = Null?
  New ObjectParameter ("V_NAME", v_NAME):
  New ObjectParameter ("V_NAME", typeof (string));    
 Var v_DESCRIPTIONParameter = v_DESCRIPTION! = Null?
  New ObjectParameter ("V_DESCRIPTION", v_DESCRIPTION):
  New ObjectParameter ("V_DESCRIPTION", typeof (string));    
 Var v_USERIDParameter = v_USERID! = Null?
  New ObjectParameter ("V_USERID", v_USERID):
  New ObjectParameter ("V_USERID", typeof (string));    
 Try
 {
  Step = (((IObjectContextAdapter) this) .ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction ("SP_INSERT_MATRIX", v_MATRIXTYPEParameter, v_NAMEParameter, v_DESCRIPTIONParameter, v_USERIDParameter, rETVAL);
 }
 Catch (Exception ex)
 {
  Var a = ex.Message;
 }
 Return step;
}
```

The data flow does it correctly, but the moment I want to run the function
SP_INSERT_MATRIX
With the call of the ExecuteFunction

I miss the error:

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 8:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'SP_INSERT_MATRIX'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 8:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

I've been with this problem all morning, could you tell me where my error is? Or how to solve it,

Thank you very much